# Debug next PHP page in Netbeans from Firefox

Tags: firefox, netbeans, xdebug

I have recently switched to using Netbeans (6.7 RC1) on a Mac, using MAMP as stack. I have Xdebug installed and working.

Previously I used Zend Studio 5.5 with the Firefox Zend toolbar. This had a great feature that allowed you to click 'Debug next page'. When you submitted the form it would then start the debug process.

How do I do something similar with Netbeans ? I would like to be able to launch the debugger from Firefox, so that all GET and POST variables were automatically passed to the debugger.

Will

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried yet, but Netbeans should have Firebug AddOn. Not sure if it does what you need.

Comment: this is used for javascript debugging. Couldn't see how it interacted with Xdebug.