# Seeking virtual machine with Xdebug working for PHP in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, virtual-machine, xdebug

I have followed *many* user guides, spent many a long hour, read these questions on S.O

[How to debug PHP with netbeans and Xdebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693074/how-to-debug-php-with-netbeans-and-xdebug)
[How to debug PHP with netbeans and Xdebug in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959525/how-to-debug-php-with-netbeans-and-xdebug-in-windows)
[How do you debug a PHP test file in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521694/how-do-you-debug-a-php-test-file-in-netbeans)
[Debug php with Netbeans - Newbie source request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029160/debug-php-with-netbeans-newbie-source-request)
[Debug next PHP page in Netbeans from Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941778/debug-next-php-page-in-netbeans-from-firefox)
[How to debug a PHP application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199342/how-to-debug-a-php-application)
[how to run php file in netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441482/how-to-run-php-file-in-netbeans)

and am currently waiting for my hair to grow back in order to tear it out again.

Anyhoo, it seems that someone else must have solved this already, so … can anyone point me at a download URL for a free virtual machine with Netbans configured for Xdebug with PHP?

Obviously it will be Linux; I would prefer Ubuntu, but will accept anything. I have a slight preference for Virtual Box, but VMware is just fine.

I am sure that this will help many people, so thanks on behalf of us all.

---

Alternatively, you may wish to post a (link to a) known to be working PHP.INI (although I appreciate that that will requier a little edtting)

Comment: Seven years later, we now have a site for [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), and I am still asking [roughly the same question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48026/linux-virtual-machine-for-php-mysql-js-eclipse-based-web-development) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't offer you a VHD download but this is how I've done mine using VirtualBox

### Networking Setup

This is probably the most important bit. Add two network adapters to your VM. The first can be a standard NAT connection so your VM can connect to the Internet. Make the second a "Host-only Adapter".

Install Ubuntu Server onto your VM.

Open `/etc/network/interfaces` and add the second adapter with a static IP in the 192.168.56.1/24 range (this is the VirtualBox host-only network subnet), eg

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# Static VBox IP
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.56.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

After restarting your VM, you should be able to connect to it on that static IP.

### I ♥ LAMP

1. Install Zend Server CE via the manual DEB method listed here - http://files-source.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-Community-Edition/zend-server-community-edition.htm#deb_installation.htm
2. Install XDebug via PECL, eg `sudo /usr/local/zend/bin/pecl install xdebug`. You may need to install some dependencies like `gcc` and `make` before this works.
3. Remove the Zend Debugger config symlink, eg `sudo rm /usr/local/zend/etc/conf.d/debugger.ini`

Configure XDebug with the following. Add this *above* the `[Zend]` section in `/usr/local/zend/etc/php.ini`

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/xdebug.so" 

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.var_display_max_data=10000
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=20
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
```

You don't need to use Zend Server however I find it's the best LAMP stack around. You can probably get by installing the default LAMP stack then installing XDebug

```
sudo aptitude install php5-xdebug
```

Answer (score 1):

The [BitNami LAMPStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/lampstack) VMWare machine includes Xdebug and it is free. However, it does not include NetBeans but we know people have gotten it to work with the appliance.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add the following to /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini on your guest machine.

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```