# XDEBUG hangs on virtual hosting domains

Tags: php, cakephp, netbeans, xdebug

when I use the regular localhost/domain with xdebug, xdebug works fine. however, I also have virtual hosting set up on my local machine so if I use xdebug and call on the domain. test.domain.com. The xdebug hangs.

I did find a clue on what it maybe. in my `php.ini` file, if I change `xdebug.remote_host=localhost` to `xdebug.remote_host=vhost_domain_name`. It works. so I guess the question is , can I setup multiple vhost domains for xdebug to look out for.

[EDIT]

I apologize. I didnt post my setting :P . Didnt realize it.

```
zend_extension ="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp"
```

Comment: This related question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165360/seeking-virtual-machine-with-xdebug-working-for-php-in-netbeans

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not "setup multiple vhost domains for xdebug to look out for" because it is Xdebug that connects to your IDE and not the other way around. The `xdebug.remote_host` value should be the hostname or IP address of the machine on which your IDE runs at.

Answer (score 1):

see [xdebug.remote_connect_back](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_connect_back)

> If enabled, the xdebug.remote_host setting is ignored and Xdebug will
>   try to connect to the client that made the HTTP request. It checks the
>   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variable to find out which IP address to use.
>   Please note that there is no filter available, and anybody who can
>   connect to the webserver will then be able to start a debugging
>   session, even if their address does not match xdebug.remote_host.

Comment: xdebug.remote_connect_back is for making sure that multiple developers can use the same Xdebug installation/configuration. It has nothing to do with "listening to multiple vhosts" as there is no such thing in Xdebug.

Comment: Yes. Just suppose virtual host is "another developer". As far as virtual host and local one can "see" each other remote_connect_back should work